# How to run Midnight Commander as a separate app, not a terminal instance?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, activities-overview, midnight-commander

Midnight Commander has a file which makes it available as a gnome app
`/usr/share/applications/mc.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Midnight Commander
...
Exec=mc
Icon=MidnightCommander
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=ConsoleOnly;Utility;FileManager;System;FileTools;
Keywords=file manager;console;
```

But when I run it, MC introduces itself as a Terminal app.
How to run it as a separate app (with the MC icon in the dock, switching apps views)?

I tried to set `Terminal=false` but that changed nothing.

It bothers me, because when I have a running MC, and I want to open a terminal, I hit the super key, then type `terminal`, hit enter, and then I realize that nothing happened because MC already works as a terminal, so I need to open a terminal as a new window.

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
GNOME 42.5
```

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is needed for this question. Different versions of Ubuntu use different versions of Gnome. Your app may not work on all of them.

Comment: @David I've updated the question with Ubuntu & Gnome version

Comment: Have you verified the app works with Gnome 42?

Comment: @David, I'm not sure you understand what's the problem. The app (Midnight Commander) works fine. I just don't want it to introduce itself as a terminal app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a copy of your `/usr/share/applications/mc.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`. You may need to create the folder `applications` if you do not already have it.
- Edit the copy ~/.local/share/applications/mc.desktop`

  1. Change `Terminal=true` to `Terminal=false`
  2. Change `Exec=mc` to `Exec=gnome-terminal --class=mccommander -- mc`
  3. Add the line `StartupWMClass=mccommander`

This will now launch `mc` in a terminal that has a distinct window class, and will be treated as a separate application.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I replaced `mccommander` with `mc` (don't know why I should name it somehow differently?), and added `mc` to `Keywords` so it's still searchable as `mc`.

Comment: The choice of the classname is entirely yours, indeed.